# Publishing single page from ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET Core project using Razor pages,
I published the project from Visual studio 2019 to an Azure web app,
Its working fine.

But when I doing a change in a single page, I want to publish the only modified page to the project,
I'm doing this from : Project menu----> Publish page.cshtml, Visual studio is telling me the file has published successfully, but I do not see any change in the online page.

Is there is any missing step after publishing the page?

Kindly help me regarding this issue.

Comment: Could you please visit **http://websiteName.scm.azurewebsites.net** and get into WWWRoot folder. Open the file and verify the changes. If the latest files exist, could you please stop and start the website. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@ZanestMahmood,
Good morning. Could you please visit https://websiteName.scm.azurewebsites.net and verify that your changes exist. If the latest files exist, then could you please try to stop and start the web app. Please refer to the URL for additional information. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I used Kudo console, I found that the only modified page is exist in (Pages) folder,
And my change is exist in this page, but the other unchanged pages are not exist in the FTP, not in the (Pagest) folder and not in the root folder, the only modified page is exist as page.cshtml, and the other files are in dll and other extensions.

Comment: @ZanestMahmood, Good afternoon. Are you see the latest content when you are browsing? Could you please also try Stopping and Starting the Azure Web Site, before browsing the site? Please advise. Many thanks.

Comment: @ZanestMahmood, after stopping & Starting the Web application. Could you please either clear the Browser Cache and/or try browsing the site in incognito mode.

Comment: Dear,
Yes I did browsing the site in incognito mode, still I don't see the changes.

Comment: @ZanestMahmood if it is OK, could you please publish the url of your website and let me know the changes. Let me browse that from my Laptop and see the output.

Comment: @ZanestMahmood, I am assuming that the .cshtml files got the update and the rest of the files are of previous publish. Could you please verify the timestamps of the files. That should give us a clue.

Comment: Dear,
As I found,  when I publish the site from VS,all the razor pages would generate into one compile file which is named like `ProjectName.View.dll`.So although when I publish a single page,it could not change in my site.
I think I should find another way for publishing my site, the way can also publish single pages.
Do you have any advice regarding this issue?

Comment: @ZanestMahmood, Could you please list of the items involved in your project 1. ASP.Net MVC Core, 2. Razor Pages, and other details. I will create a sample project and host it. Then I will change and redeploy. Let's find out whether I am also facing similar issue.

Comment: Dear My project is ASP.NET core 3.1 (Using razor pages not Controllers) and I published it to Azure app service (windows not Linux)